# Accessing Raw Hard Drive with FUSE

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I'm looking at building a toy file system for a project and heard that FUSE was a starting point for a lot of researchers. I know that FUSE runs out of the user space, but is able to read and write from a raw device that is also on the system?

I have done some research into this, but couldn't find a concrete answer.

Comment: It can do anything that any normal application can do.

Comment: And that includes e.g. reading from `/dev/sda1`

Comment: So would that just be reading from a pointer address then?

Comment: It's good for mounting a filesystem to a mount point on the OS's filesystem. It's more of an interface than a filesystem itself.